# Indy 10 smtp authenticate throws access violation

Tags: email, delphi, authentication, smtp, indy

Iam using Delphi 5 and Indy 10 recently downloaded from [fulgan](https://indy.fulgan.com/).
The access violation error occurres when the supplied credentials are incorrect. Authenticate function seems to produce the error.
 It is also impossible to get past the access violation error, resulting in program shutting down without any warning. 
Here is an example code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var IDSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
 Idmessage1: TIDMessage;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IDSMTP1 := TIdSMTP.Create;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  try
    with IDSMTP1 do begin
      Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      Port := 465;
      Username := 'email@gmail.com';
      Password := 'password';
      AuthType := satDefault;

      IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1];
      IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;

      UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
    end;

    Idmessage1 := TIDMessage.Create;
    try
      with Idmessage1 do begin
        Subject := 'test';
        From.Address := 'email@gmail.com';
        From.Name := 'testname';
        Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'email@gmail.com';
      end;

      with IDSMTP1 do begin
        if not Connected then
          Connect;
        try  
          Authenticate;
          Send(IdMessage1);
        except
        end;
        Disconnect;
      end;

    finally
      Idmessage1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IDSMTP1.Free;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've tested TIdSMTP with Gmail many times, so I know it works, unless this is a Delphi5-specific bug (wouldn't be the first time). What does the debugger show for the call stack when the error occurs? I might have an idea what is failing, but I need to check the code. As for "impossible to get past", that is simply not true. A `try/except` can catch access violations. You code is only using `try/finally`, which won't catch the exception. But even if you don't catch it, your code is in a UI event handler, so the VCL message loop will catch the exception. Your app should not be terminating.

Comment: Yes, this is a known Delphi 5 bug (related to call stack corruption when calling an overloaded method that has an open array parameter, which is something `Authenticate` does internally). This bug was fixed in Delphi 6. One workaround in Delphi 5 is to recompile Indy with Stack Frames enabled and Optimizations disabled, but that doesn't always work. I do have a code fix, but it is really ugly, so I haven't checked it in, I need to find a cleaner solution that doesn't break compatibility with later versions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used `try/except` after `Connect` and also tried replacing `finally` with `except`.